# Incorrect SQL generated by SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a function that returns a query that would fetch «New priorities for emails» by given account id.
First it selects a domain name for that account, and then selects a data structure for it.
And everything should be OK IMO, but not at this time: SQLAlchemy is generating SQL that is syntactically wrong, and I can’t understand how to fix it. Here are the samples:

```
def unprocessed_by_account_id(account_id: str):
    account_domain = select(
        [tables.organizations.c.organization_id]).select_from(
        tables.accounts.join(
            tables.email_addresses,
            tables.accounts.c.account_id == tables.email_addresses.c.email_address,
        ).join(tables.organizations)
    ).where(
        tables.accounts.c.account_id == account_id,
    )
    domain_with_subdomains = concat('%', account_domain)
    fields = [
        tables.users.c.first_name,

        …
        tables.priorities.c.name,
    ]
    fromclause = tables.users.join(
        …
    ).join(tables.organizations)
    whereclause = and_(
        …
        tables.organizations.c.organization_id.notlike(
            domain_with_subdomains),
    )
    stmt = select(fields).select_from(fromclause).where(whereclause)

    return stmt

print(unprocessed_by_account_id(‘foo’))
```

So it generates:

```
SELECT
  users.first_name,
  …
  priorities.name
FROM (SELECT organizations.organization_id AS organization_id
      FROM accounts
        JOIN email_addresses
          ON accounts.account_id = email_addresses.email_address
        JOIN organizations
          ON organizations.organization_id = email_addresses.organization_id
      WHERE accounts.account_id = :account_id_1), users
  JOIN
    …
  JOIN organizations
    ON organizations.organization_id = email_addresses.organization_id
WHERE emails.account_id = :account_id_2 AND
      priorities_new_emails.status = :status_1 AND
      organizations.organization_id NOT LIKE
      concat(:concat_1, (SELECT organizations.organization_id
                         FROM accounts
                           JOIN email_addresses ON accounts.account_id =
                                                   email_addresses.email_address
                           JOIN organizations
                             ON organizations.organization_id =
                                email_addresses.organization_id
                         WHERE accounts.account_id = :account_id_1))
```

But the first

```
(SELECT organizations.organization_id AS organization_id
      FROM accounts
        JOIN email_addresses
          ON accounts.account_id = email_addresses.email_address
        JOIN organizations
          ON organizations.organization_id = email_addresses.organization_id
      WHERE accounts.account_id = :account_id_1)
```

Is redundant here and produces

```
[2017-05-29 23:49:51] [42601] ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
[2017-05-29 23:49:51] Hint: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
[2017-05-29 23:49:51] Position: 245
```

I tried to use `account_domain = account_domain.cte()`, but no luck, except that the subquery went to `WITH` clause as expected.
Also I tried `with_only_columns` with no effect at all.
I think that Alchemy is adding this statement, because it sees it inside `WHERE` clause and thinks that without it the filtering will result in an error, but I’m not sure.
Also I must mention than in previous version of code the statement was almost the same except there were no `concat(‘%’, account_domain)` and `notlike` was `!=`.
Also I tried inserting `alias` here and there, but had no success with that either. And if I manually delete that first statement from the select is plain SQL, then I’d receive expectable results.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: could you post the model declarations please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a subquery as a value, you need to declare it [`as_scalar()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.SelectBase.as_scalar):

```
domain_with_subdomains = concat('%', account_domain.as_scalar())
```